# How to get Array inside Array data to another array in angular 7

Tags: arrays, angular7

I have a json data set with arrays.I want to retrieve data from that set to another array.

this is my json data

```
[
    {
        "user": [
            {
                "userActivityId": "08d66e8f-0f2f-3162-4d1d-b0307df0b532",
                "userId": "08d65df8-5a1c-4879-b8b6-f583bafa8084",
                "userName": "Dorothy",
                "photoUrl": "08d65df8-5a1c-d841-cff6-444e72fa08f2",
                "createdOn": "2018-12-31T01:13:23.363154",
                "itemType": 0,
                "itemId": "08d66e8f-0f2f-2efa-db7a-ab313ff89e7c"
            },
            {
                "userActivityId": "08d66e8f-19cf-7c9c-1e07-00c9e7c37fc0",
                "userId": "08d65df8-5a1c-4879-b8b6-f583bafa8084",
                "userName": "Dorothy",
                "photoUrl": "08d65df8-5a1c-d841-cff6-444e72fa08f2",
                "createdOn": "2018-12-31T01:13:41.190886",
                "itemType": 1,
                "itemId": "08d66e8f-19cf-a711-47a1-9690d9f6bf5e"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user": [
            {
                "userActivityId": "08d66e3f-61e0-55db-f57d-5d434738d366",
                "userId": "08d6630e-325b-3474-5b5c-3c07af8063b8",
                "userName": "Supun",
                "photoUrl": "1",
                "createdOn": "2018-12-30T15:43:02.314203",
                "itemType": 0,
                "itemId": "08d66e3f-61df-c79d-dac4-f16f1142d526"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want to do is,I want to get this data set inside user array values to single array.

This is the way I followed,

```
friendsStufs: any[];
 this.userService.getFriendsStufs(this.authService.currentUser.id).subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(user => {
    user.forEach(stufs => {
      this.friendsStufs.push(stufs);
    });
  });
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
  this.alertify.error('Can retrieve friends stufs');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate all user object in a single array.

```js
let data = [ { "user": [ { "userActivityId": "08d66e8f-0f2f-3162-4d1d-b0307df0b532", "userId": "08d65df8-5a1c-4879-b8b6-f583bafa8084", "userName": "Dorothy", "photoUrl": "08d65df8-5a1c-d841-cff6-444e72fa08f2", "createdOn": "2018-12-31T01:13:23.363154", "itemType": 0, "itemId": "08d66e8f-0f2f-2efa-db7a-ab313ff89e7c" }, { "userActivityId": "08d66e8f-19cf-7c9c-1e07-00c9e7c37fc0", "userId": "08d65df8-5a1c-4879-b8b6-f583bafa8084", "userName": "Dorothy", "photoUrl": "08d65df8-5a1c-d841-cff6-444e72fa08f2", "createdOn": "2018-12-31T01:13:41.190886", "itemType": 1, "itemId": "08d66e8f-19cf-a711-47a1-9690d9f6bf5e" } ] }, { "user": [ { "userActivityId": "08d66e3f-61e0-55db-f57d-5d434738d366", "userId": "08d6630e-325b-3474-5b5c-3c07af8063b8", "userName": "Supun", "photoUrl": "1", "createdOn": "2018-12-30T15:43:02.314203", "itemType": 0, "itemId": "08d66e3f-61df-c79d-dac4-f16f1142d526" } ] } ],
    result = data.reduce((r,{user}) => {
      user.forEach(o => r.push({...o}));
      return r;
    },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you please explain what is  the meaning of 3 dots inside push method?
r.push({...o})

Comment: `...` is `spread syntax`, it is used to create a new object here.